# How can I delay file uploads until the form is submitted in React?

Tags: reactjs

I want to upload an excel sheet when I select Add radio button and click on the Upload button.

Now My file is uploading as soon as I click on choose file. I want that to happen when I click on Upload button.

I see the file data in console as soon as upload the file.

I am beginner learning react. Thanks in advance.

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
import * as XLSX from "xlsx";
import "./../accordian.css";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Radio from '@material-ui/core/Radio';
import RadioGroup from '@material-ui/core/RadioGroup';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import FormHelperText from '@material-ui/core/FormHelperText';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';


function Upload() {
    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
        formControl: {
            margin: theme.spacing(3),
        },
        button: {
            margin: theme.spacing(1, 1, 0, 0),
        },
    }));
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [files, setFiles] = useState()

    const classes = useStyles();
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');
    const [error, setError] = React.useState(false);
    const [helperText, setHelperText] = React.useState('Choose wisely')

    const handleRadioChange = (event) => {
        setValue(event.target.value);
        setHelperText(' ');
        setError(false);
    };

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        console.log(event)
        event.preventDefault();

        if (value === 'Add') {
            setHelperText('File Added');
            setError(false);

        } else if (value === 'Replace') {
            setHelperText('File Replaced');
            setError(true);
            setFiles(files)
        } else if (value === 'Remove') {
            setHelperText('File Removed');
            setError(true);
        }
        else {
            setHelperText('Please select an option.');
            setError(true);
        }
        setFiles(files)
    }

    const addFiles = (files) => {
        files.map((file) => {
            var filereader = new FileReader();
            filereader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
            filereader.onload = (e) => {
                const bufferArray = e.target.result;
                const wb = XLSX.read(bufferArray, { type: "buffer" });
                const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
                const wsname1 = wb.SheetNames[1];
                const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];
                const ws1 = wb.Sheets[wsname1];
                const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, ws1);
                setItems(data);
            };
        });
    };
    console.log(items, 'item');
    return (
        
        <div className="container-fluid">

            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <FormControl component="fieldset" error={error} className={classes.formControl}>

                    <section className="heading">
                        <input
                            type="file"
                            className="input-field"
                            accept=".csv, .xlsx,.xls,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel"
                            onChange={(e) => {
                                const file = [...e.target.files];
                                //console.log("here", file);
                                // const file1 = e.target.files[1];
                                addFiles(file);
                            }}

                            multiple
                        />

                    </section>

                    <RadioGroup aria-label="quiz" name="quiz" value={value} onChange={handleRadioChange}>
                        <FormControlLabel value="Add" control={<Radio />} label="Add" />
                        <FormControlLabel value="Replace" control={<Radio />} label="Replace" />
                        <FormControlLabel value="Remove" control={<Radio />} label="Remove" />
                    </RadioGroup>

                    <FormHelperText>{helperText}</FormHelperText>

                    <Button type="submit"
                        variant="outlined"
                        color="primary"
                        className={classes.button}
                    >
                        Upload
                    </Button>
                </FormControl>
            </form>

        </div>
    );
}
export default Upload;
```

Comment: One question at a time, please. Your second question is inappropriate here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add 'files' onChange to your state;

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState()
```

Then onChange occurs:

```
setFiles(files)
```

And then when you handleSubmit is where you process your file.
And always print your data for debugging, so I added some lines so you can know what's going on!

```
const [files, setFiles] = React.useState(undefined)

const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    console.log('handleSubmit')
    // You need to use foreach not map
    let dataArray = []
    files.forEach(file => {
        console.log('proccessing file')
        var filereader = new FileReader();
        filereader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        filereader.onload = (e) => {
            const bufferArray = e.target.result;
            const wb = XLSX.read(bufferArray, { type: "buffer" });
            const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
            const wsname1 = wb.SheetNames[1];
            const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];
            const ws1 = wb.Sheets[wsname1];
            const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, ws1);
            // Always update your state at the end.
            // Because render method will be called whenver your state changes.
            // setItems(data);
            dataArray.push[data]
        };
    });
    console.log('data', data)
    setItems(data)
    
    console.log(event)
    event.preventDefault();

    if (value === 'Add') {
        setHelperText('File Added');
        setError(false);
    } else if (value === 'Replace') {
        setHelperText('File Replaced');
        setError(true);
    } else if (value === 'Remove') {
        setHelperText('File Removed');
        setError(true);
    }
    else {
        setHelperText('Please select an option.');
        setError(true);
    }
}

const addFiles = (newFiles) => {
    console.log('add files')
    setFiles(files)
};

console.log(items);

return (


    <div className="container-fluid">

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <FormControl component="fieldset" error={error} className={classes.formControl}>



                <section className="heading">
                    <input
                        type="file"
                        className="input-field"
                        accept=".csv, .xlsx,.xls,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                            const file = [...e.target.files];
                            //console.log("here", file);
                            // const file1 = e.target.files[1];
                            addFiles(file);
                        }}

                        multiple
                    />

                </section>

                <RadioGroup aria-label="quiz" name="quiz" value={value} onChange={handleRadioChange}>
                    <FormControlLabel value="Add" control={<Radio />} label="Add" />
                    <FormControlLabel value="Replace" control={<Radio />} label="Replace" />
                    <FormControlLabel value="Remove" control={<Radio />} label="Remove" />
                </RadioGroup>

                <FormHelperText>{helperText}</FormHelperText>

                <Button type="submit"
                    variant="outlined"
                    color="primary"
                    className={classes.button}
                >
                    Upload
                </Button>




            </FormControl>
        </form>




    </div>
);
```

...

Comment: If I do this way I get infinity loop error. I am not sure if I understood correctly. I have updated the code above please check

Comment: I have updated my answer and added some comments. Hope this will be close enough!